# $_SESSION with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have two php files.

**addbasket.php**

```
<?php    
session_start();   
$link = $_SESSION['link'];  
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {......}
?>
```

and

**index.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();   
$_SESSION['link'] = mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","dbname");  
$link = $_SESSION['link'];
.... 
?>
```

> **The file addbasket.php is called by Ajax and given Parameters for article (number) and amount (number)**

but the mysqli_query doesnt work. 
It seems like the `$_SESSION['link']` is not there in addbasket.php.
It can't be the Session, because the `$_SESSION['userid']` is there, right and can be echoed.

What could be the Problem here?

Comment: what is `$_SESSION['link'] = mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","dbname");` suppose to do?

Comment: it works on all pages, except the Ajax call.

Comment: its for Setting the mysqli_connect for all pages, so if the host changes, i dont have to Change the text on all php files (about 50) i just can change it in the index.php

Comment: yes but you can't store a resource like a the database connection within the session

Comment: oh no.. :( so i have to Change it on all pages when im finished on my localhost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SESSION` can only store serializable data.

`mysqli_connect` returns a resource. Resources are *not* serializable.

You'll have to instantiate that DB connection in every request.

Edit:
OK, now I understand your actual problem.
What you need is some form of this:

**db.php**

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","dbname");
```

**index.php**

```
require 'db.php';
$r = mysqli_query($link, 'SOME QUERY...');
....
```

**addbasket.php**

```
require 'db.php';
$r = mysqli_query($link, 'SOME OTHER QUERY...');
....
```

Comment: You need to understand how your webserver works. When you `include` or `require` a file in index.php that code runs in the same process but when you make an AJAX request the webserver starts a new process that does not share anything with the one index.php was running in.

Comment: yes..but index is: `<?php session_start(); 
$_SESSION['link'] = mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","dbname");
$link = $_SESSION['link'];
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
if (isset($_SESSION['userid']))
 {
  $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
  $user=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE ID = '$userid'");
   }  
?>` and it works...

Comment: Well of course it works. `$_SESSION` is just an Array. It is _magically_ serialized (and saved somewhere) after all your code has run and unserialized when you call `session_start`. Between these two steps, as I said, it's just an ordinary Array.

Comment: Oh okay... do you know a Solution to my Problem that i want to have the db Connection only on one page? instead of all 50?

Comment: There is none. You will have to open a connection to the database in every request. You can obviously reuse it globally throughout the lifetime of the whole request. That's why your code _works_ in index.php, `$_SESSION` is global.

Answer (score 1):

You can't serialize a resource object and that's why you can't hold it in the session

Comment: but it works on normal php's that are not called by ajax

Comment: I think that by default it uses the current opend DB link, that's why its working on some cases - when you've opend a connection during the current script execution

Comment: isnt there a way to store the link in "text" wich is added to the script on load? like an echo before script run?...

Comment: No. you can use persistent connection, but i wouldn't recommend you to do it. you just have to open a new link each time you calling the PHP script

Comment: oh...that means changing the link in all 50 page when the adress changes?

Comment: for taht you can use constants http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php create a constant with the address and just change it on a single file. the other files just use the constant itself

Comment: `define("link_" "mysqli_connect("localhost","test","test","dbname");")`
and then use
`mysqli_query($link_....)? `

Comment: no, just the address, in the `mysqli_connect` pass the constant `link_`

Comment: but then a session would work too?

`mysqli_connect(echo $_SESSION['x']);`